# ESP8266 400 Bad Request

Tags: mysql, arduino, mamp, http-status-code-400, esp8266

I am developing a Webapp that uses an ESP8266 on a Nodemcu to send Sensor Data to a local Server (MAMP) running on my Computer and then inserts it in a MySQL Database. I am using the Arduino IDE btw. This is the Code to Send the Data:

```
const char* host = "192.168.1.6";
const char* passcode = "test";    

void sendData(float t, float h) {
WiFiClient client;

if(client.connect(host,8888)){
  Serial.println("Webserver connected");

//Send Data 
String dataCmd = "GET /data.php?code=";
dataCmd += passcode;
dataCmd += "&temp=";
dataCmd += t;
dataCmd += "&hum=";
dataCmd += h;
dataCmd += " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.6\r\n";
dataCmd += "User-Agent: ESP8266_HTTP_Client\r\n";
dataCmd += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
client.print(dataCmd);
Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial.println(dataCmd.length());
}
sent++;
client.stop();
}
```

Although I can connect to the Server I get a Status 400, Bad Request. The access log displays the following:

```
192.168.1.5 - - [15/Jan/2016:13:13:57 +0100] "GET /data.php? code=test&temp=23.00&hum=37.00 HTTP/1.1" 400 226 "-" "-"
```

I guess it is something with the GET Request, but I tried quite a lot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shall we guess the error as well, or are you going to share it with us?

Comment: Probably it should start with GET data.php?... , so remove the / before the GET keyword.

Comment: @Shadow Yea sorry edited it already. I am getting a Bad Request. And also removed the /. No change though

Comment: In the log there seem to be a space between the  ? and code parameter. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, there should be an extra \r\n after keep-alive to indicate the end of the header section

Comment: @Shadow just a typo!

Comment: @Shadow \r\n did the trick. Thank you so much!!

Comment: ..and do not "keep-alive".